# It should be queried in the event handler for a control that has CausesValidation=True

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error

> Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place. It
>   should be queried in the event handler for a control that has
>   CausesValidation=True and initiated the postback, or after a call to
>   Page.Validate.

Here is my code:

```
public override void Validate(string grp)
    {// redioHospitalType this my radio button based on this type checking this.. 
        if (redioHospitalType.SelectedValue == "CH")
        {
// reqfieldNoofHospitals -this is my required field ID
            bool enableValidators = true;
            reqfieldNoofHospitals.Enabled = enableValidators;
            base.Validate();
        }
    }

  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Page.Validate("signup");// here signup is validation group name .
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {

            }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You could use a `CustomValidater` and it's `ServerValidate` event. You don't call the method that validates yourself. It is called implicitly when you call `Page.Validate()`.